# No reconoce el perfil del usuario que ingresa al sistema

Tags: php, login, cuenta-usuario

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] !== '') {

    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["email"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $password = sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES)))));

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\" AND password = \"$password\";");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['profile_id'] = ($row['profile_id']==1);
        header("location: ../dashboard.php");
    } else {
        $invalid = sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
        header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
    }
} else {
    header("location: ../dashboardGeneral.php");
}
?>
```

Pero no importa sino es administrador siempre carga lo mismo, me pueden ayudar

Comment: mete en parentesis `()` => `(email ="$email" OR username="$email")`.. aparte no se lo que quieres conseguir con esto `($row['profile_id']==1)` y lo demás...necesitas un buen reformato de código... y muestra los errores que te aparecen...

Comment: Lo que quiero es que si es administrador me muestre una pagina y si es usuario normal me muestre otra, no me da ningun error.

Comment: Para eso tienes que guardar en la bd el role de cada usuario .. y luego cuando quieren ingresar a la web compruebas el role del usuario y lo redireccionas en una u otra página...

Comment: Hace un **echo  $query** y pasa el resultado

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, si quieres que cuando sea administrador te valla a una página y si es otro tipo de usuario a otra, tienes que definir el tipo de usuario, con una instrucción **if** selecciona una o otra. Si puedes colocar la estructura de tabla **user** para poderte ayudar mejor en lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_admin` tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL
)

Comment: Una cosa siempre que sea código colócalo dentro de tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, donde de asumo que **profile_id** es tipo de rol y el **1** responde al administrador.

> Redirección para la página del administrador  **header("location: ../dashboard.php")**;
>
> Redirección para la página de el resto de los usuarios: **header("location: ../dashboard_pagina2.php");**

```
  session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] !== '') {

    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["email"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $password = sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES)))));

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email ='".$email."' OR username= '".$email."') AND password = '".$password."'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['profile_id'] = $row['profile_id'];

            if($_SESSION['profile_id'] == 1){

                 header("location: ../dashboard.php");  

            }else{ 

               header("location: ../dashboard_pagina2.php");  

            }
        } else {
            $invalid = sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
            header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
        }
    } else {
        header("location: ../dashboardGeneral.php");
    }
```

Comment: Amigo fue todo un éxito muchas gracias

Comment: De nada para eso estamos, me alegro que te halla sido útil.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['profile_id'] = ($row['profile_id']==1);
    header("location: ../dashboard.php");
```

Cámbialo por

```
$_SESSION['profile_id'] = $row['profile_id'];
  if ($_SESSION['profile_id'] == 1){
    header("location: ../dashboard.php");
 }
```

Comment: No me reconoce la diferencia entre un usuario y otro